# What causes droplets to form on the surface of the ocean while raining?

Tags: surface-tension

We were watching the surface of the water in the inlet when it began to rain. The water droplets would hit the surface and appear to bounce out and form a sphere riding the water surface. Sometimes the balls would stay formed for 5 seconds before melting. Is it the salinity that prevents the droplet from being immediately absorbed?

Comment: elastic scattering and momentum conservation? surface tension , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QhqFR-Ku5M